# How to display the sql query in phpmyadmin as the older versions?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Older Version
[image]

How to display the red marked box in newer version of phpmyadmin? which execute the command without displaying it.

New Version
[image]

I needed the sql query to be displayed for use in my php scripts.

Comment: if you can click on "Settings" tab and check each available options there ..

Comment: @Mit.agile sure tried, but it is all about the SQL History of the manual executed queries, not the phpmyadmin queries

Answer (score 0):

I found it is working inside tables, and creating tables shown in the SQL History.

[Inside Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0zhb.png)

[SQL History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD7Em.png)

Only Creating DB is not shown anywhere, so it is acceptable for my needs.
Thanks for your time